# Set Precision for double

Tags: c++

I am trying to set the two decimal numbers for double type data entered by the user, and I have the proper header file , but the result on the display is only integer, no decimal ?
I do really appreciate any help.

Comment: [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) are useful.

Comment: Note that internally you do not set the precision for floating point types.  You format the number for display to two decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the following format.

```
cout << setprecision(# of places past decimal) << fixed << varName << endl;
```

The fixed Input output manipulator is what tells it that you are setting the precision for the number of places after the decimal point.